# how to delay PHP script until Mysql insert query is committed

Tags: php, mysql

In the website I am developing the Users have to sign Up or register.

when the users submits the form for registration the user should get logged automatically with his UserName...

Now, I insert the data into Mysql database followed by retrieving the same data from database with Select statement but the problem is that Select statement is executed faster then the Insert (or something) and it results in Fatal error... I want the PHP script for retrieving data wait until the Insertion is committed... How can I do that ? thanks

Comment: would you mind sharing some code, some error message or something at all for us to go on?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Could you provide your current source code? PHP is executed synchronously, thus the next line is evaluated only after the previous is done.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether query has been executed successfully or not.

`$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}`

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, requests to a RDBMS such as MySQL are always performed synchronously. Then, the behaviour you describe might come from a not-commited transaction initiated prior your INSERT SQL statement. Indeed, if the transaction is not finished and you perform a SELECT SQL statement on the previously inserted table, you will see nothing new because the RDBMS does not know yet if the inserted data must commited or not.

The first thing you might want to check is whether or not a transaction is begun:

- Look in the execution stack if an SQL transaction is begun prior your call to INSERT.
- Check if the configuration parameter autocommit is set or not (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).

If you are not performing formal transactions in your code, enabling autocommit might be a solution. Otherwise, simply do not forget to send a COMMIT statement when appropriate.

Comment: 1. How check if the INSERT statement is committed ?. 2. how to make php script wait until the INSERT statement is committed?

Comment: Simply COMMIT after the INSERT. You should see the new data appear ;)!

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar problem.

After being unable to fix it properly, i've ended UP adding a `sleep(1);` after my INSERT/UPDATE query.

It seems that the server may not been working properly, because queries are executed syncronous. Im feeling that my problem is related to memory or filesystem/cache delays at VPS. Data takes around 0.100 to be really updated, when it should be reflected at runtime.

I am not sure where the problem really comes, just telling you "how to delay PHP script".

Regards.